# Johnny Ola's cut finger in The Godfather 2 - accident or what?

Tags: the-godfather-2

I noticed something in *The Godfather: Part II* when, during Hyman Roth's birthday cake presentation, Johnny Ola seems to cut his finger when preparing to cut the cake.  He grabs a napkin to wrap the finger, and holds the finger to his mouth. The next scene, he's leaning on the rail as though it never happened, and nothing more is ever made of the event. 
Was this a plot point I missed, or a real accident, or what?

Answer (score 10):

He didn't cut himself, he got some **white icing** on his finger after messing around with the cake (taking the sparkler off and rearranging it) and he licked it off and then wiped it with his napkin.

**Source:** I watched the scene in HD just now. :) It's definitely white and not blood.

Comment: Thanks, Walt.  That makes a lot more sense than what I thought I saw.  Appreciate the fast response!

Comment: +1 I'm still curious about why this moment was included. Was it scripted, or just something that happened spontaneously and was subsequently included? (not that I expect an answer... just interesting to ponder)

Comment: I could easily see it either way. Certainly it makes the scene look authentic. You probably know that Luca Brassi's rehearsal of his speech to Vito was something the actor was doing and FFC decided to include it in the film.